# How to convert a dictionary to a list of keys, with repeat counts given by the values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counting

I need your help to solve a problem.

I want to convert a dictionary `d = {key1:value1, key2:value2}` into
`list= [keys1, keys1, ... (value1 times), keys2, ... (value2 times)]` without using a nested loop.

Example:

```
d1 = {4: 1, 3: 2, 12: 2}
```

The code should produce the output:

```
l = [4, 3, 3, 12, 12]
```

This is what I have:

```
for key, value in nums1.items():
        temp = (str(key))*value
        nums2.append(int(temp))
print(nums2)
```

Which gives: `[4, 33, 1212]`, but should give `[4, 3, 3, 12, 12]`.

The complexity should be O(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). It features an [`elements()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements) that yields all elements with the correct count:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list(Counter(d1).elements())
[4, 3, 3, 12, 12]
```

If you want to implement this yourself, I think the most readable version is this `for` loop:

```
from itertools import repeat

result = []
for k, count in d1.items():
    result += repeat(k, count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `repeat`, which yields an element a specified number of times, with `chain` to combine everything together:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

source = {4: 1, 3: 2, 12: 2}

list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(element, times) for element, times in source.items()))
```

Output:

```
[4, 3, 3, 12, 12]
```

Comment: The same could be written a bit shorter as `list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, source.items())))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comprehension like below:

```
list(chain.from_iterable(map(int, ((str(k) + ',') * v).split(',')[:-1]) for k, v in d1.items()))
```

**Code**:

```
from itertools import chain

d1 = {4: 1, 3: 2, 12: 2}

print(list(chain.from_iterable(map(int, ((str(k) + ',') * v).split(',')[:-1]) for k, v in d1.items())))
# [4, 3, 3, 12, 12]
```

To avoid all those fancy splits and `map`, you can go for:

```
[k for k, v in d1.items() for _ in range(v)]
```

which also outputs the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
d1={4:1,3:2,12:2} 
ans =[]
for key,value in d1.items():
    ans.append((str(key),)*value)
print(ans)
flattened = []
list(flattened.extend(item) for item in ans)
print(flattened)
```

Output:

```
[('4',), ('3', '3'), ('12', '12')]
['4', '3', '3', '12', '12']
```

Answer (score 0):

For less complex amd more readable soultion, in addition, no extra packages are required, your code could be as the following:

```
nums1 = {4: 1, 3: 2, 12: 2} 
nums2 = []
for key, value in nums1.items():
    nums2 += [key]*value

print(nums2)
```

which outputs with the following:

```
[4, 3, 3, 12, 12]
```